# nginx doesn't support ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 cipher suite

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have a device that is trying to connect with the following `Client Hello` captured from Wireshark:

[image]

It looks like the only Cipher Suite it supports is `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`, I'm therefor trying to enable this with `nginx`.

```
events {

}

http {
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/nginx.key;
        server_name xxx.yyy.zzz;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256';
    }
}
```

I don't get an error when running `nginx` with that config:

```
$ docker run -p 443:443 -v (pwd):/etc/nginx/certs -v (pwd)/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf nginx
```

However, the list of supported ciphers comes back null with `sslscan`:

```
$ sslscan localhost
Version: 1.11.12-static
OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016

ERROR: Could not open a connection to host localhost (::1) on port 443.
Connected to 127.0.0.1

Testing SSL server localhost on port 443 using SNI name localhost

  TLS Fallback SCSV:
Server supports TLS Fallback SCSV

  TLS renegotiation:
Session renegotiation not supported

  TLS Compression:
Compression disabled

  Heartbleed:
TLS 1.2 not vulnerable to heartbleed
TLS 1.1 not vulnerable to heartbleed
TLS 1.0 not vulnerable to heartbleed

  Supported Server Cipher(s):
$
```

I'm not an ops guy, so I'm not familiar with setting up servers. I just need to get this IoT device to connect to my server.

So how can I go about enabling the `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256` cipher suite with nginx?

Comment: Who built the Docker container you are using? Where did it come from?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's the official `nginx:latest` from Dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

Comment: Hm. I'm pretty sure the default image is built on alpine, which is extremely stripped down. Try one of the images built on stretch instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can view available ssl_ciphers using:

```
openssl ciphers
```

To get a more "eye friendly" output try:

```
openssl ciphers | egrep --color 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'
```

to check if your desired cipher is available to nginx.

Comment: In this case the official nginx container from Dockerhub doesn't have the `openssl` binary installed